# Purpose of [RequiredBy] directive in Systemctl

Tags: unix, rhel7, systemctl

If we have the [Requires] directive in the [Unit] part of a service unit file then why do we also need [RequiredBy] directive in the [Install] section of the
service unit file..I understand that the directives under the [Install] part is executed when the service is enabled(service has to restart after server reboot)
so even if i don't specify the [RequiredBy] directive then also after the server reboot anyways the systemctl is going to check the [Requires] directive and will start the required service/target unit...Please clarify this i am newbie to Systemctl utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do different things. Actually, one is the mirror image of the other.

`[Requires]` configures dependencies on other units; the units listed here are activated together with the unit, and if any of them fails to start, the unit is not activated.

`[RequiredBy]` specifies a list of units that depend on the unit. When this unit is enabled, the units listed here gain automatically a `[Require]` dependency on the unit; consequently you do not need to specify a `[Require]` for each of these units.

Source: [RHEL7 SysAdmin guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html)